# add auto_incremente PK in MYSQL SERVER

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, auto-increment

I am learning MYSQL, I did this structure

[image]

but, I dont know how put autoincrement into workbench

I try :

```
alter table Profesores CHANGE id id int not null auto_increment;
```

but I have the below error, because is a foreigner key that other table

```
'fk_Profesores_has_Grados_Profesores1' of table 'PRUEBA.Profesores_has_Grados'
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: One way: break the foreign key relationship, make the change, recreate the foreign key

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your ID with auto increment, you must first remove the relationship with the other table (Foreign Key) and then change the table.